# Returning a reference to a list of objects

Tags: java

I created two classes: class DVD and class ListOfDVDs. I have a method inside my class ListOfDVDs to add a new DVD to the list (which is just a array of DVDs). However, now I am supposed to create a method, which would read a textfile containing multiple DVDs, add all of them to the ListOfDVDs and return a reference to a newly created ListOfDVDs object which contains all of the DVDs from the textfile. However, I am not sure how to create a new object and call it's methods from inside my method. I have to create a new ListOfDVDs, add DVDs from the file to it and then return it. Not sure how to do this. I already have a method to add a DVD to the list: it's listOfDVDs.add. Thanks

My code so far looks like this:

```
public class listOfDVDs {

private DVD[] DVDs;

public listofDVDs() {
    DVDs = new DVD[0];
}

public void add(DVD newDVD) {
    if (newDVD == null) {
        return;
    }

    DVD[] newDVDs = Arrays.copyOf(DVDs, DVDs.length + 1);
    newDVDs[newDVDs.length - 1] = newDVD;
    DVDs = newDVDs;
}

public static listOfDVDs fromFile(String filename) {
    Scanner sc = null;
    String name = null;
    int year = 0;
    String director = null;
    try {
        sc = new Scanner(new File(filename));
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            name = sc.next();
            year = sc.nextInt();
            director = sc.next();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("file not found");
    } finally {
        if (sc != null) {
            sc.close();
        }
    }

}
```

}

```
 public class DVD {
private String name;
private int year;
private String director;

public DVD(String name, int year, String director) {
this.name=name;
this.year=year;
this.director=director;
}
  }
```

Comment: Also above code doesn't compile. Please post valid code.

Comment: Why don't you use a list instead of an array?

Comment: added all I could, array is a recommended way for this task

Comment: Clean up your code so we can understand it. What class is fromFile in ?

Comment: in class listofDVDs

Comment: How can class `Video` have a constructor named `DVD`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need a type named `ListOfDVDs`?
You might just want a `java.util.List` of `DVD`. You would write that as:

```
List<DVD> list = new ArrayList<DVD>();
```

If you must have a type listOfDVDs you should start its name with a capital letter by convention: `ListOfDVDs`. But again this would probably contain a `java.util.List`. You say you want an array. A List would be better, but let's stick to what you want.

Given your updated code, you would do:

```
listOfDVDs list = new listOfDVDs();

while (sc.hasNext()) {
    name = sc.next();
    year = sc.nextInt();
    director = sc.next();

    //create a DVD.
    DVD dvd = new DVD(name, year, director);
    //add it to the list
    list.add( dvd );
}

//return the result to the caller of the method.
return list;
```